# Not able to hit request with special characters in Karate framework

Tags: karate, web-api-testing

I have a get request like below:

**Request URL :**

https://environmentname.abc.xyz.com/search/v1/xyzdata?filters(Sector==ABC^Currency==ABC|XYZ|IJK|DEF|LMN|OPQ^Settlement Type==AnyThing)

When I hit this request with the get method, I receive the following error:

Java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query.

I tried to put filters as parameters too in the request but still received the same error.

Let me know if anyone knows how to resolve it?

Comment: this works perfectly for me:
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* param filters = "(Sector==ABC^Currency==ABC|XYZ|IJK|DEF|LMN|OPQ^Settlement Type==AnyThing)"
* method get